# Traversing tables? (FF 4)

Tags: jquery, parsing, javascript-injection

I'm trying to parse http://www.MMORPG.com/gamelist.cfm using injected JQuery, and it works fine down to the table level, using $("#gamelisttable > tbody > tr"), but if I try, say, iterating over it:

```
var games = $("gamelisttable > tbody > tr");
for(var i = 0; i < games.length; ++i)
    games[i].children().css("font-weight", "bold");
```

I get errors like `games[i].children is not a function`). The type of `games[i]` is showing as `[object XrayWrapper [object HTMLTableRowElement]]`. How do I traverse deeper than this, and why isn't it working?

My actual goal is to, for each row, compare data in that row to a list of criteria, and if they match, find the second cell element, take the link in that cell element, and bold the link text. Perhaps there's a better way to be doing it.

Comment: What is your question? What is your code? There is nothing to do here.

Comment: I see code, I see a question, so what is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with *games[i]* your are accessing the element at position i in the jQuery list, which will return the plain HTML-object. Try wrapping it with the $-function.

```
$(games[i]).children().css(...)
```

Comment: Well that's that problem solved. I feel quite foolish now. Is there any way to iterate over the jQuery list without having to wrap with the $ each time?

Comment: I don't know a way that gives you an jQuery object for each item automatically... maybe it is unwanted because of a potential overhead if you do not need the jquery functionality? But maybe you are happier with a shorter version. what you are currently doing can also be achieved by using $('yourselector').children().css('font-weight', 'bold'). If you want to do other things use $('yourselector').children().each(function() {$(this).css('font-weight', 'bold)});

Comment: Turns out there's a `.eq()` function which works nicely for this: `$(games[i])` becomes `games.eq(i)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, did only know about the :eq selector, but good to know the function.